# Unable to access an enumerated datatype from within another class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Hoping someone can help me with this as I've done some scratching & searching I'm still overlooking something obvious... I've defined a simple enumerated data type:

```
typedef enum {
    kLow = -1,
    kMid,
    kHigh
} MyMode;
```

And made an instance variable of this type in my ClassA:

```
@interface ClassA : UIView {
    MyMode myMode;
}
@property (nonatomic) MyMode myMode;
@end
```

And then **myMode** is synthesized in the @implementation. Now in another class I reference ClassA

```
@interface ClassB : UIView {
    ClassA *classA;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) ClassA *classA;
@end
```

Finally, in a method w/in ClassB I'd like to test for the state of ClassA's myMode property. I've tried

```
if (classA.myMode == kLow)
```

and this gives me the "request for member in something not a structure or a union" error. Casting didn't make a difference.

```
if ([classA myMode] == kLow)
```

gives me a "No '-myMode' method found".

I *believe* my headers and includes are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `@interface` for ClassA before you can refer to ClassA's properties. Typically, this means you need to `#import "ClassA.h"` in ClassB.m, before ClassB's `@implementation`.

Comment: I'm a dumbass. I had the @class ClassA; declaration in the @interface...but forgot the import in @implementation..and put it out of my mind... garr!  well, thx!